# Templating and escaping with Coffeescript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

This below selector in some coffeescript that I wrote keeps giving me trouble.

```
$('span[data-id="#{cat_id}"]').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle icon-button fold')
```

When compiled and run, the text inside the quotes becomes:

```
span[data-id="#{cat_id}"]
```

I tried changing the single quotes on the outside of the selector to double quotes, but then I get a runtime error:

ExecJS::RuntimeError in Application#handle_404
Showing /Users/michaeldiscenza/Documents/RUN_source_repos/run_portal/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #33 raised:
[stdin]:222:88: error: unmatched OUTDENT
        $('span[data-id="#{cat_id}"]').children().attr('class', 'icon toggle collapse')

I've tried concatenating`"/'" + selector + "/'"`  , but that didn't work either.

Comment: Tried `$('span[data-id=#{cat_id}]')` (without double quotes around attribute selector value) ?

Comment: I think then the single quotes mean that the #{} won't be interpreted, so I end up getting  `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: span[data-id=#{cat_id}]`

Comment: String interpolation doesn't happen inside single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("span[data-id=#{cat_id}]")
```

I guess the inner quotes where unnecessary, but double quotes where still needed on the outside to allow for interpretation of the #{}